# как одновременно запустить pgadmin и клиентскую в apache?

Tags: apache, nuxt.js, pgadmin4, pgadmin

Конфиг апаче виглядит так /etc/apache2/sites-enabled 000-default.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
 

 ProxyPass /api http://0.0.0.0:3000
 ProxyPassReverse /api http://0.0.0.0:3000

 ProxyPass /socket.io ws://0.0.0.0:3000/socket.io
 ProxyPassReverse /socket.io ws://0.0.0.0:3000/socket.io

 ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/


</VirtualHost>
```

сайт прекрасно работает открывается, api тоже, но в данном случае пропадает доступ к панели pgadmin4, если удалить последние две строки то появится доступ к pgadmin, как решить проблему? чтобы и сайт открывался и доступ к pgadmin4 был

у меня клиентская(nuxt) на порту 8080 и бекенд на 3000

Comment: есть вариант pip3 install pgadmin4  и запуск через sudo pgadmin4, но иногда не работает после обновлений. системный пакет перед этим удалить.